# old website to new website

Tags: 7, migrations, upgrading

Old website is running on live. The version of the old website is drupal 6. Last two months ago, I receive a task to create new website by using drupal 7 to replace old one. That time i have 0 knowledge of drupal. Now ready to replace old one and face problem. Old website is drupal 6. New one is drupal 7. Sure have problems.That why i decide to duplicate old website and database to sub domain. Purpose is to upgrade old website from drupal 6 to 7. Old website in sub domain display succesfully, but the link all point to site listing of the sub domain

FYI, I had managed to replace new website D7 to old website D6 successfully. However, the solution is not base on migrate D6 To D7. This question will be remain unanswered...

Comment: how did you try to upgrade from D6 to D7 ?

Comment: I cant try because when I duplicate database and copy old website to new sub domain something happen. Home page is displayed correctly but all the hyperlink are wrong. Everything is link to my sub domain site map

Comment: Sorry is not site map is site listing

Comment: your question is fairly confusing. Try editing it answer these questions I have about it: are both D6 and D7 site online now? What do you mean with subdomain (is that the D7 version)? What is the main domain (the D6 version?) What is "site map" or "site listing"? What did you do in the apache configuarion file to separate both sites, ect,etc. See how confused I am with just reading the question? Note: constructive critique, just trying to help. But if we don't understand the question, we can not answer it, only keep guessing, ok? Enhance it also to avoid it gets closed via moderators ...

Comment: I very sorry. Here is the situation. Old website is running on live. The version of the old website is drupal 6. Last two month ago, I receive a task to create new website by using drupal 7 to replace old one. That time i have 0 knowledge of drupal. Now ready to replace old one and face problem. Old website is drupal 6. New one is drupal 7. Sure have problems.That why i decide to duplicate old website and database to sub domain. Purpose is to upgrade old website from drupal 6 to 7. Old website in sub domain display succesfully, but the link all point to site listing of the sub domain.

Comment: No need for sorry, everybody starts new some day, right? How URGENT is this problem? I am busy right now (not a lot of time), but if you want I'll try to help, step by step, OK? To move forward: please EDIT your question and integrate what is relevant from your prior comment. Also confirm that you did perform some typical UPGRADE steps to go from D6 to D7 (do you know what UPGRADE in Drupal means?)

Comment: I had successfully upgrade from drupal core 7.32 to 7.34 once. Regarding about drupal 6 i have not touch anything related to upgrade. I only migrate drupal 6 website to my localhost and sub domain and both face same problem. At localhost, website display successfully but when I click on any link it goes to my localhost. Example: "localhost/example.com" I click on about us. The link will go to "localhost/example.com/aboutus", but it display localhost page. Same happen to my sub domain

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is contact your web hosting provider and see if you can go back to working copy of your website. After you have a working copy of your website download that into a local environment. I would recommend to this either a Mac or Linux machine (ubuntu os what I user).

Once you have your local environment you can start trying migrating from D6 to D7. You should never try an migration a production site.

From here you can use `drush sup` to upgrade your website. After your website is been successful upgrade from D6 to D7. You should consider uploading that to your web hosting provider.

Comment: As you suggest, I had downloaded to my localhost. As well as the database. Website load successfully but the link all goes to localhost.....Any reason why this happen?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with .htaccess file.Or I think you try drush. to upgrade first on local then on live.

Comment: I had downloaded the test it on my localhost. I do feel the problem is at htaccess or setting.php. At the setting.php, I quite sure my database set correctly and base url is commented.

Comment: What you mean by all links are gone ? If you do not have clean url enable in your local server most likely you would not be able to find any page that is not your front-page. Check if you have clean urls enable on your server.

Comment: Do you know when you key "localhost" in the URL? It will display WAMP server page. All the link goes to that page...

Comment: You probably have an index.html or a wrong configuration with your server. You need to either created a virtual host. Or remove the WAMP configuration. I personally do not like WAMP so I have not used it in a really long time ago.

Comment: I dun feel is the WAMP server problem. I tested test server as well....and result still the same

Answer (score 1):

I'll use this answer to try to help/guide @peifa. I'll do so by enhancing my answer in multiple steps (iterations), depending on which parts need more details etc as per peifa's knowledge. To Peifa: please add comments to this answers to confirm, ask extra questions, etc where appropriate, OK? And try to EDIT your question instead of adding comments to it (that is not really helpful, since too time consuming to digest I feel). Like the comment about "local host", put that in the question, and then delete that comment again. To anybody else: feel free to edit my answer to refine, correct, etc.

Assumptions: current live (production) site is D6, ultimate deliverable is to REPLACE it entirely with a D7 equivalent, in production status also.

Approach: clone the D6 version from production environment to some TEST environment, which is what in the original post (OP) seems to be called "subdomain". I'm assuming you're using apache as the webserver (if not: what else)? And since I do not see "localhost" or "virtualbox" or anything similar, I assume anything related to the upgrade is happening somewhere online. If not please enhance the OP to claify.

**Step 1**: update your a apache configuration, to add the config about the root folder for the D7 site and the subdomain name (as it will be used in the URL to surf to it)..

**Step 2**: make sure you're aware of the [upgrade instructions](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade).

**Step 3**: Upgrade Drupal core (and the database) from D6 version to D7 version. Need I provide more details on that?

**Step 4**: Upgrade relevant contrib modules from D6 to D7. Need I provide more details on that?

Comment: Thank you.  

Assumptions: current live (production) site is D6, ultimate deliverable is to REPLACE it entirely with a D7 equivalent. D7 is tested on localhost and test server (my server sub domain) D7 is not production site yet. 

Approach: clone the D6 version from production environment to some TEST environment, "subdomain". D6 is host at the webserver under public_html directory. In the public_html directory i create a folder call testing and set it as my sub domain. I clone d7 from public_html to testing folder. I download from server and clone to my laptop WAMP server as well.

Comment: Now is the issue. D6 cant upgrade either at my localhost nor sub domain. I take my localhost WAMP server as an example. All the hyperlink link to localhost even my url state the correct path. Cant even login to user because it link to localhost as well.

Comment: I'm in a rush right now. But we are making a little progress: it's much clearer now what your question is (still not perfect). And you recreated the problem in your localhost environment, so we can now try/experiment without depending on 3rd parties, way to go! Next question: can you update your question by including the relevant parts of your .htaccess files, of your LOCALHOST setup (no need for the .htaccess from your live site). That might help to pinpoint the problem ... PS: I'll edit my answer later on today (this comment seems more important to me right now to get you going)

Comment: I believe is htaccess file problem. Here is the situation.
In the localhost, website all the link actually working fine!!!!! YEAH!!! When I successfully login as administrator, all the admin link will redirect to localhost page. OH NO..... My htaccess file pretty long (around 118 lines) and I have no ideas what is it about.. I change to default htaccess (around 16 lines). The result is all the link includes website all goes to localhost. As a result I believe is htaccess file problem, but how am i explain? I do not really understand what is the code about.

Comment: I wonder is it something related to this? 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-fRewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Can you try this experiment please: step a = rename your htaccess file to some other name (put it aside temporarely) step b = visit the Drupal status page within your site (to see if there are any special msgs) step c = check if Drupal recreated a default htaccess file again that might just work and step d = verify if your problem still exists. step e = update your question by including these extra steps and the result of what you got from it, ok?

Comment: I will try tml morning. (10 hr later from now.)

Comment: Step1: rename htaccess (sites/default/files) Step2: UR: localhost Step3: Click www.example.com Step4: Result: Website and the link is fine. Admin still goes back to localhost page. htaccess never auto create Step5: Rename htaccess (home directory) Step6: URL: Localhost Step7: Click www.example.com Step8: Result: website will display few second and auto link back to localhost page. Htaccess will not auto create.

Comment: OK, I think I start to better understand ... Could it be something in your configuration file of your apache server (an automatic forwarding of an URL contained in it)?

Comment: I using WAMP server. In the wampmanager.conf, I dun see any url.

Comment: Completely different idea to just verify (eliminate as possible cause): check the content of your "hosts" file, locate (in win 7) in dir windows\system32\drivers\etc ... if in there for some reason localhost has some funny setting, then that might need review ... check for any line that does NOT start with a '#' (= is not commented out)

Comment: 127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
This is the only code start without #.

Comment: I just realize my website is running below localhost page.

Comment: What does "below" mean in this context? And also: how does this discovery help you to resolve your issue?

Comment: I dun think it help to solve my issue. Do you know a localhost page which display server information, domain name etc....The website display at the bottom of all these information.

Comment: Finally found the problem. I disable "Clean URL" and its works......

Comment: @peifa ... have you noticed how "some anonymous voter" came along and seems to not have liked my attempt to help you debug your issue? And without leaving a comment ... How nice ... I hope someone will soon UNDO the current -1 score ...

Comment: I think they are not against you. They against me. I not sure why. I ask just some question which I completely clueless and I get vote down. Lol. Anyway I manage to replace from D7 to D6, but not using this method. Thank you pierre for helping me alot.

Comment: @peifa : thx for reply. Looks like we might want to further "discuss" this downvoting topic itself in the "new user experience" chat room I created ... If you want to do so, please find me there some day, ok? By the way: my downvote disappeared ... I bet I know who voted it up again! So thanks for that also!